# CoreUI Sidebar renders above page content

Tags: typescript, vue.js, core-ui

I am using CoreUI to create my layout for my app and I got stuck when I tried to add the Sidebar. The Sidebar is rendered, but I cant get my `router-view` into remainig space on the right. I don't want to place it `fixed` because it will be over my content, then.
[image: Current Display]
Here is my code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <CNavbar expand="lg" color-scheme="light" class="bg-light">
      <CContainer fluid>[Some links here]</CContainer>
    </CNavbar>
    
    <CSidebar visible>
      <CSidebarNav>
        <CSidebarBrand>Sidebar Brand</CSidebarBrand>
        <CNavItem href="#">
          <CIcon  customClassName="nav-icon" :icon="icon.cilUser" />
          Nav item
        </CNavItem>
      </CSidebarNav>
      <CSidebarToggler @click="$store.commit('toggleUnfoldable')" />
    </CSidebar>

    <router-view /> <!-- This should be on the left of the Sidebar, not below. -->

    <CFooter>[Footer stuff here]</CFooter>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added a flexbox around menu and the content, with the content sized to 100%.